# Is there a way to tell mypy to ignore checks on overridden functions?

Tags: python, mypy

I changed a function in a specific library by monkey patching it with a different function.

##### Library's send function

```py
def send(content: str):
  ...
```

##### Monkey patch

```py
def new(content: Union[str, dict[str, str]]):
  return send(content)

library.send = new
```

But using that function results in a mypy error:

##### Code that resulted in an error

```py
library.send(
  {"ja": "Japanese text", "en": "English text"}
)
```

##### Error text

```py
Argument 1 to "send" has incompatible type "Dict[str, str]"; expected "str"
```

Is it possible to make exceptions for certain functions to avoid this?

Comment: Unsupported for now: read here https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2427
You can use `# type: ignore[assignment]` or try `setattr(library,'send',new)`